# Неверный результат программы

Tags: ассемблер, masm

```
push 360
mov eax, 7
mul [esp]
pop edi
```

Не могу понять, почему данная программа выдает результат `728`.

Comment: Наверное, потому что по адресу `[esp]` находится 104? :) Куда у вас `esp` показывает?

Comment: А какой по вашему должна выдавать?

Comment: [esp] как раз правильно на вершину стека указывает, где как раз и лежит 360, младший байт которого и есть 104

Comment: @Mike Ну! ну так на ЧТО он указывает? на байт, на слово, на что?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали размер операнда и происходит умножение AX на один байт из памяти. Используйте явное указание размера операнда.

```
push 360
mov  eax, 7
mul  dword ptr [esp]
pop  edi
```